# how to change rules name? (chefboost)

Tags: python, decision-tree, c4.5

I have a question about chefboost.
I want to exchange rules name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIGK2.png)
It is chefboost putput.
I am not good at English and need additional information, please reply

```
config = {'algorithm': 'Regression'}
model = chef.fit(df, config, target_label='label')
model = chef.fit(df, config, target_label='label')
```

I want to the name of the rules to a variable and save it.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you. **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied,